# wxComboBox returns Hex

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have got problems with my wxComboBox. I set two Values (P 01 and P 03) in with a wxString. Now I Start a event with

```
Connect(ID_DEV, wxEVT_COMMAND_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, 
    wxCommandEventHandler(MF_Setup::OnDev));
```

When I now try this:

```
wxString devval[10] = cb_Setup_4->GetValue();
std::stringstream ss_dev;
ss_dev << cb_Setup_4->GetStringSelection();
```

I got something like *0x23e1d8* or *0x23e4b4* back...

What I have to do to solve my Problem? I want the String back, or, this will be much better, the Index of the String (0 = P 01; 1 = P 03) like GetSelection () should do (but also delivers only a Hex...)

-Casisto

(using wxW 2.9.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is solving my problem:

```
int dev = cb_Setup_4->GetSelection();
```

Comment: I can do this earliest in two days

Answer (score 0):

```
wxString devval[10] = cb_Setup_4->GetValue();
```

`GetValue()` can't possibly return an array. I'm surprised this statement even compiles.

```
std::stringstream ss_dev;
ss_dev << cb_Setup_4->GetStringSelection();
```

`GetStringSelection()` returns a `wxString` which is not stream-insertable. You need to use the `c_str()` function to get the `const char *` that you can insert to the stream.

```
ss_dev << ( cb_Setup_4->GetStringSelection().c_str() );
```